# Uncertainty calculation through integration and correct analysis methodology

Tags: dataset, statistics, time-series, error-handling

> *In the following text, uncertainty refers to standard deviation.*
>   My methodology and notation was based mainly on the book ["A Student's Guide to Data and Error Analysis"](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/engineering/engineering-general-interest/students-guide-data-and-error-analysis?format=PB) by H.J.C. Berendsen."

### Summary:

I have a timeseries which I use in a few equations and get averages and uncertainties. I do that up to a point where I have to integrate the averages. So the question is, **what happens to uncertainty when you integrate the averages?** My problem might arise from a mistake in methodology so **I would appreciate any feedback on the followed process as well**.

### Details:

I am trying to calculate the uncertainty of a number that is computed as part of an analysis code. While I can compute the average number, I encounter some issues with the uncertainty for which I would appreciate any advice from more experienced analysts.

**My methodology was:**

1. From 30 simulations, I have obtained 30 timeseries files that each contain 100000 lines of a z-axis position-fluctuation of a molecule. **Therefore I have 30 files files that each contains two vectors: t and z**
2. **For each position/file**, I use the z timeseries to calculate 
   the variance of the timeseries $var(z)$ and the variance of the mean of the timeseries $var(\langle z \rangle)$. *The latter is done with block averaging (b.a.)*. Both these methods have a textbook defined, relative standard deviation:
   $$ var(z) \, [units] \pm \sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}} $$
   $$ var(\langle z \rangle) \, [units] \pm \sigma_{<χ>}^2 $$ 
   where $ \sigma_{<χ>}^2 $ is the squared standard error ($ \sigma_{<χ>}=\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$) computed from b.a.
    The above are used as input in a diffusion equation:
   $$ D(z)=\frac{var(z)}{\big[ \frac{n \cdot var(\langle z \rangle) }{var(z)} -1 \big] \frac{dt}{2}} $$ 
   where $n$ and $dt$ are constants. *For this step, I also used two failed alternative methods that I explain in the end.*
3. Then I used the above to calculate the average diffusion coefficient D for each of the 30 files. To find the uncertainty of each average, I combined the errors based on [error propagation algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty) where I considered (as a first approximation) the covariance $\sigma_{AB}$ as 0. In the end, I obtained a new "summary" file with 30 rows and 4 columns, containing the average position, average Diffusion, absolute uncertainty and relative uncertainty:
   $$  z  \,,  D(z)  \,, \pm \Delta D(z) \,, \pm \frac{\Delta D(z)}{ D(z) }$$
4. From the same simulation, I also obtain a similar "summary" file that contains 30 rows and 3 columns with the average position, Gibbs free-energy and its absolute uncertainty (standard deviation):
   $$  z \,,  \Delta G(z)  \,, \pm \Delta \Delta G(z) $$
5. I then combined both summary files to compute a resistance profile with the equation:
   $$ R(z) = \frac{\exp \big[ {\frac{\Delta G(z)}{k_BT}}\big] }{D(z)} $$
   where $k_BT$ was a constant. To combine $\Delta G(z)$ and $D(z)$ I first  I interpolated them in a common, dense z-grid. Therefore, I ended up with a file with 500 values of resistance together with the absolute and relative uncertainty:
   $$  z \,,  R( z )  \,, \pm \Delta R(z) \,, \pm \frac{\Delta R(z)}{ R(z) }$$
6. To get the final result which is permeation, I integrated these 500 values, according to the equation:
   $$ P=\frac{1}{\int_{z_{min}}^{z_{max}}R(z)dz} $$
   and I obtained the average P by performing a trapezoidal approximation over the 500 $R(z)$ values.

**My question is, what happens to the uncertainty? How does it propagate through the integral?**

**Also, do you have a more appropriate alternative to my methodology?** I am trying to find some guidelines on how to do a "correct" data analysis but the available information is either too theoretical or too vague. **For example, would it make any difference in this case to perform fitting on the $D(z)$, $\Delta G(z)$ and $R(z)$ profiles, before integration? If yes, how would I calculate the uncertainty for each and for the $P$?**

Thanks a lot for any help or advice! :D

> In step 2, I tried 2 more things:
>
> 1. instead of calculating the uncertainties of $var(z)$ and $var(\langle z \rangle)$ from the textbook, I used bootstrapping to
>      create 100 new timeseries of z, for each position/file. And
>      then calculated 100 different diffusions which I used to calculate the
>      average and s.d. The method was returning the same statistics for the
>      timeseries (which was expected) but the final Diffusion was extremely
>      oscillatory (was even negative), therefore I dropped the method.
> 2. I tried to use block averaging for the calculation of D, but Python was refusing to do recursive block averaging (I might had a bug in my
>      code as well). Anyway, I quickly abandoned the idea as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to my question which in my opinion is correct (or at least has a point). Nevertheless it would be nice to have a validation from someone that might know more on the topic.

Since the average is calculated with a trapezoidal (which in reality is a summation) then the standard deviation can also be calculated by uncertainty propagation algebra for addition.

Based on [Wikipedia for trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule): 
$$ \int_c^d f(x) dx \approx (d-c) \left[ \frac{f(c)+f(d)}{2} \right] = \left( \frac{d-c}{2} \right) f(c) + \left( \frac{d-c}{2} \right) f(d)$$

which will follow the [2nd uncertainty propagation rule from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Example_formulas):
$$ f=aA+bB$$

with:

- $ a = b = \frac{d-c}{2}$
- $ A = f(c) $
- $ B = f(d) $

In terms of Python3 code that translates to:

```
import numpy as np

# FUNCTIONS
def uncAddition(A=1.,B=1.,sigmaA=0.,sigmaB=0.,a=1.,b=1.,sigmaAB=0.):
    f =  (a * A) + (b * B)
    sigmaf = np.sqrt( (a * sigmaA)**2 \
                    + (b * sigmaB)**2 \
                    + (2 * a * b * sigmaAB) )
    return f, sigmaf


# MAIN
# Data: is an nx2 array that contains n number of f values 
#           and their absolute standard deviation
# x:    is the independent variable of the f values
# Obviously x and f should have the same number of rows

integralAve=0.
integralStD=0.
for i in range(1,len(data[:,0])):
    trapzPartAve,trapzPartStd = uncAddition(A=f[i-1,0],
                                            sigmaA=f[i-1,1],
                                            a=(x[i]-x[i-1])/2.0,
                                            B=f[i,0],
                                            sigmaB=f[i,1],
                                            b=(x[i]-x[i-1])/2.0) 
    integralAve += trapzPartAve
    integralStd += trapzPartStd

print(integralAve,integralStd)
```